# fuzzy string matching with term weights

Tags: python, string, information-retrieval

I'm working on an application that attempts to match an input set of potentially "messy" entity names to "clean" entity names in a reference list.  I've been working with edit distance and other common fuzzy matching algorithms, but I'm wondering if there are any better approaches that allow for term weighting, such that common terms are given less weight in the fuzzy match.

Consider this example, using Python's `difflib` library.  I'm working with organization names, which have many standardized components in common and therefore cannot be used to differentiate among entities.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher  
e1a = SequenceMatcher(None, "ZOECON RESEARCH INSTITUTE", 
                            "LONDON RESEARCH INSTITUTE")
print e1a.ratio()
0.88

e1b = SequenceMatcher(None, "ZOECON", "LONDON")
print e1b.ratio() 
0.333333333333

e2a = SequenceMatcher(None, "WORLDWIDE SEMICONDUCTOR MANUFACTURING CORP",
                            "TAIWAN SEMICONDUCTOR MANUFACTURING CORP")
print e2a.ratio() 
0.83950617284

e2b = SequenceMatcher(None, "WORLDWIDE",
                            "TAIWAN")
print e2b.ratio() 
0.133333333333
```

Both examples score highly on the full string because `RESEARCH`, `INSTITUTE`, `SEMICONDUCTOR`, `MANUFACTURING`, and `CORP` are high frequency, generic terms in many organization names.  I'm looking for any ideas of how to integrate term frequencies into fuzzy string matching (not necessarily using `difflib`), such that the scores are't as influenced by common terms, and the results might look more like the "e1b" and "e2b" examples.

I realize I could just make a big "frequent term" list and exclude those from the comparison, but I'd like to use frequencies if possible because even common words add *some* information, and also the cutoff point for any list would of course also be arbitrary.

Comment: [Whoosh](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/wiki/Home) looks interesting, particularly its [`scoring`](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/api/scoring.html) module and [whoosh.reading.TermInfo](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/api/reading.html?highlight=frequency#whoosh.reading.TermInfo)'s `doc_frequency()` and `weight()`

Comment: Do you have access to the full corpus of names to fuzzy match with? If so, you can use tf-idf to train a fuzzy matching model.

Comment: You could split the strings and compute the difference on every piece. This would help you on _some_ situations where you have almost same names but with just one word difference. But this probably isn't robust enough for what you want to do.

Comment: @Björn Lindqvist can you elaborate?  I have a list of maybe 30,000 authoritative names, but that doesn't exhaust the possible inputs.  In other words, a name might be entered that isn't in the list. I also have collected a list of many misspellings for the entities in the authoritative list.  I'd love to train a classifier (if that's what you're suggesting, though I might not be following) to do the job but haven't been able to come up with a good design (e.g., what features?).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a weird idea for you:

Compress your input and diff that.

You could use e.g. [Huffman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) or [dictionary coder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_coder) to compress your input, that automatically takes care of common terms. It may not do so well for typos though, in your example, London is probably a relatively common word, while misspelt Lundon is not at all, and dissimilarity between compressed terms is much higher than between raw terms.

Answer (score 2):

how about splitting each string into a list of words, and running your comparison on each word to get a list which holds the scores of word matches. then you can average the scores, find the lowest/highest indirect match or partials...

gives you the ability to add your own weight.

you would of course need to handle offsets like..

"the london company for leather"

and

"london company for leather"

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a general solution will never match your idea of similarity. As soon as you have some implicit knowledge about your data, you have to put that somehow into code. Which imediately disqualifies a fixed existing solution.

Perhaps you should have look at http://nltk.org/ to get an idea of some NLP techniques. You don't tell us enough about your data, but a POS tagger might help to identify more and less relevant terms. Available databases with names of cities, countries, ... might help to clean up the data before processing it further.

There are many tools available, but to get high quality output, you will need a solution which is customized for your data and use case.

Comment: I'm happy with an application specific solution.  My data are just entity names, unfortunately, without any context.  I like the idea of POS tagging, but I'm afraid since that I have just the names something like 95% of what comes back from the tagger will be NNP's.

Comment: POS taggers are not restricted to the "default" tags. You can tag an example set yourself, using your own tags (CITY, NAME, TYPE, ...) and train a tagger using that data. There are more options than I can write down here and to give more hints I would have to "play" with your data. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I am just proposing another different approach. Since you mentioned that the entity names are coming from a reference list, I am wondering if you have additional context information, like co-author names, product/paper titles, address w/ city,state,country?

If you do have some useful context as above, you can actually build a graph of entities out of the relations between them. Relations could be, for example:

```
 Author-paper relation
 Co-author relation
 author-institute relation
 institute-city relation
 ....
```

Then it's time to use a graph-based entity resolution approach described in detail at:

- http://linqs.cs.umd.edu/basilic/web/Publications/2007/bhattacharya:tkdd07/bhattacharya-tkdd.pdf
- http://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/1903/4021/1/4758.pdf

The approach has a very good performance on co-author-paper domain.